# How can a facebook bot send a message via messenger that the user can then share to their timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm writing a facebook bot and want to enable the user to be able to post or share a URL, description and hashtag to their own wall, from within the messenger app.

Looking at messenger it appears as though the only native sharing options are to share to other messenger users or post an update to your day, not post to your facebook wall.

The only way I can think of doing this is having a standard FB share button hosted on the page I want them to share, but that would not be as fluid a user experience for the user, it would be lovely if there was a way within the messenger app that I could enable the user to share the URL with description and hashtag directly.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn’t seem to be available directly in Messenger. The URL redirect version of the Share- or Feed dialog is probably the quickest way to get this working, if you just send the URL to the messenger user - but I suppose that will still open in a webview then, and whether or not login works automatically in there you’d have to check.

Comment: Thanks it's a shame as like you say they may not be logged in to Facebook in their native browser. Seems like my only option right now. Appreciate the reply thanks.

Comment: One option is you could use the Facebook Login SDK to create a login page that the user can open in a webview. When they login you can ask for the permission to post to their wall. Once they've accepted this permission your app can then post directly to their wall. It's a bit awkward though as it'll only work if the user completes the login and accepts the permissions.

Comment: Yep, it's the only way